# What is Launch Control and why does it want to receive keystrokes?

Tags: security, privacy, macos

What is Launch Control and why does it want to receive keystrokes?

Suddenly this warning popped up:

[image]

Searching for this message returns zero results.

[https://www.google.com/search?q="launchcontrol+would+like+to+receive+keystrokes+from+any+application"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22launchcontrol+would+like+to+receive+keystrokes+from+any+application%22)

"LaunchControl" would like to receive keystrokes from any application. (verbatim string if someone search for it in the future)

Comment: This one? https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/

Comment: This actually makes it even weirder. Yes, I have - installed July 10 2017 (version 1.32.2 - current version is 2.5.2). Why does a seven year old application suddenly start asking for permissions!?!?

Comment: Care to show your macOS update history? Usually an os update starts reporting this in my experience. It’s super legit software, been a long time staple for me.

Comment: @d-b Because something it does all the time was silently allowed before and now is not.  It's not the app asking you, it's the OS asking you.

Comment: @bmike But why does such an app require access to keystrokes? It is a regular windowed app, that have no need to overlay the screen or something like that.

Comment: Probably the QuickLaunch menu bar tool,  but I can’t speak for that developer other than they have excellent support whenever I ask them a question